# oozie job submission fails with check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, oozie

```
2013-04-29 14:47:28,686  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000000-130429144458254-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-130429144458254-oozie-oozi-W@mr-node] Error starting action [mr-node]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
  at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:412)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:392)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:760)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:911)
  at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:211)
  at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:59)
  at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:277)
  at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:121)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:83)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:76)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:495)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:474)
  at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService$1.run(HadoopAccessorService.java:362)
  at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService$1.run(HadoopAccessorService.java:360)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
  at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.createJobClient(HadoopAccessorService.java:360)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.createJobClient(JavaActionExecutor.java:954)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:711)
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831226/running-wordcount-sample-using-mrv1-on-cdh4-0-1-vm-solved

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have a hadoop-env.sh .How do i add the variable mentioned in the above post ?

Comment: What versions / distributions of Hadoop and Oozie are you currently using?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was given by a typo in workflow.xml: `<name-node>{$nameNode}</name-node>` instead of `<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>`.